# How to start activity from imported module in the main app (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, import, pjsip

I have created a simple sip call using pjsip android library and wish to add it as a module to my main Android app. So far i have imported sipcall app as module using import Gradle project. So in the below image i have imported app in main app. Now how can i start activity from module in mainapp. I have tried to add dependency from module into mainapp, but its empty as schown. i would highly appreciate for any suggestion.

[image]

[image]